# Does Firebase.functions().httpsCallable auto authentication the token or do I need to manually getIdToken() and authencation using firebase admin sdk

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Does Firebase.functions().httpsCallable auto authentication the token or do I need to manually getIdToken(), pass them thru the header and authenticate using firebase admin sdk on my server?

Do I have to do this step to verify my token on firebase?

Client

```
Firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()

request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
```

Server

```
firebaseAdmin.auth()
    .verifyIdToken(accessToken)
    .then(decodedIdToken => {
        return firebaseAdmin.auth().getUser(decodedIdToken.uid);
    })
    .then(user => {
        // Do whatever you want with the user.
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Callable functions automatically receive and validate the auth token.  The uid you get from the context is guaranteed to be the authenticated end user.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) shows what you have available.

Comment: using functions.https.onCall ato auth the request but does functions.https.onRequest auto auth the request? they did not state here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you found this helpful, please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

(I just spent an hour trying to figure this out in July of 2023)

For me, the issue was a problem with the emulator. Apparently, there was a bug introduced back in late 2022 that caused the emulator to remove the auth token (even though you can see it getting passed in the network request)!

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5210 goes into deep detail about the issue and what was done to fix it.

However, this problem appears to remain if you are using [2nd gen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade) functions. I had to switch from 2nd gen back to 1st gen to get the emulator to work again.